# Can not load Dylib in Objective-C Cocoa Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, dylib

When I use external dylib, there're problem when I run the builded App.
Since I added EVN link to dylib file, and Run in Xcode no problem, however when I build it and click from builded app, there're problem couldn't load dylib.

Note: If I copy "dylib" to "usr/local/lib" it can fix. However I don't want to copy dylib to "usr/local/lib".

[image]

Click Run(Play) from Xcode no problem
[image]

However when click run from builded app there're still issue on loading dylib file
[image]

Embedded Binary added however still has issue
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You suppose to add your framework to "Embedded Binaries" list.
Click the project name => General =>Embedded Binaries.

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for your advices. However, I added however still has same issue.

Comment: clean the project, if you use the real device to debug , remove the app from your device, then build again... hope it helps you